# How do I assign values to items/products in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I assign monetary values to specific products in a spreadsheet? For instance, one column would have apples, oranges and bananas, but each of these has a value, so that once quantity is inserted in another column I could automatically calculate total value?

Comment: You need simple Formula to Multiply Quantity with Unit Price!

Comment: *so that once quantity is inserted in another column I could automatically calculate total value* Does it mean that you insert new quantity into new, previously empty, cell? or you re-write cell altering previous value? In another words - does all inserting history values are stored?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the word "apple" to mean some numerical value in a formula, or you would have a numerical value associated with apple in an adjacent column, and use that value in the formula, possibly by looking up "apple" to find it, or something else?  Will the products always be a limited fixed list or is the list subject to change?  If it is a long list or subject to change, one way is easier to maintain than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to "**Named Ranges**". In Excel we can give a name to a particular cell. For Example, you can enter **$2** amount in cell "B2" and give the cell a name "Apples". Now in when you have the Quantity in cell "F2" you can simply refer to cell "B2" by typing "Apples". So you formula will be `=F2*Apples`.

Please find below the link to a sample file with Named Ranges used: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1StLs9E6EJUTomu52Bzi9m6AEP4dJn2jD

[image: Named Ranges]

**Resources:** 
You can also know more about Named Ranges in the following links: 
Link 1: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64 
Link 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDaA3hgQwpQ